# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, text

I'm using Python 3.5, 32-bit on Windows 10.

While I am aware that questions regarding this error message have been asked and answered frequently, I still can`t figure out why my code or the corresponding  .txt file actually cause this error.

The code is a 1:1 copy from a Python beginner book and a derivative of this code where I only changed the name of the dictionary and used another .txt file worked fine.

Here is the code:

```
woerter={}
fobj=open("Woerterbuch.txt","r")
for line in fobj:
   zuordnung=line.split(" ")
   woerter[zuordnung[0]] = zuordnung[1]
fobj.close()

print(woerter)
```

And here is the corresponding .txt file:

```
Spain Spanien
Germany Deutschland
Sweden Schweden
France Frankreich
Italy Italien
```

The code will produce the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\Python-Programme\Dateiausleseprogramm2.py", line 5, in <module>
        woerter[zuordnung[0]] = zuordnung[1]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You probably have empty lines, or lines without a space on them, so `zuordnung` ends up as a list with just one element.

Comment: Then `zuordnung[1]` tries to access the second element of a line with only 1. It's probably a trailing newline in the text file.

Comment: try inserting a `print(zuordnung)` line in between your `split()` and the `woerter` assignment. This can help you track down the error. Is your `woerterbuch.txt` only 5 lines long?

Comment: Isolate the input line it dies on. My guess is that it'll have no space, but maybe a tab character.

Comment: Yes, it is only 5 lines long because it  is just a program that i have written for exercise purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given code and file do not reproduce the error.  However, if I add another line feed (empty line) to the file, *that* produces the error you give.  I removed the leading blanks in both files, and added a couple of tracing print statements to your code:

```
woerter={}
fobj=open("Woerterbuch.txt","r")
for line in fobj:
   zuordnung=line.split(" ")
   woerter[zuordnung[0]] = zuordnung[1]
   print (zuordnung)
fobj.close()

print(fobj)
print(woerter)
```

Without the blank line at the end of the input file, get the output I wanted:

```
['Spain', 'Spanien\n']
['Germany', 'Deutschland\n']
['Sweden', 'Schweden\n']
['France', 'Frankreich\n']
['Italy', 'Italien\n']
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='so.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
{'Germany': 'Deutschland\n', 'Sweden': 'Schweden\n', 'Italy': 'Italien\n', 'Spain': 'Spanien\n', 'France': 'Frankreich\n'}
```

*With* the blank line, I can reproduce your problem.  The **print** statements make the immediate cause to be obvious:

```
['Spain', 'Spanien\n']
['Germany', 'Deutschland\n']
['Sweden', 'Schweden\n']
['France', 'Frankreich\n']
['Italy', 'Italien\n']
['\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 6, in <module>
    woerter[zuordnung[0]] = zuordnung[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Note that I removed leading blanks from the data file you posted: these make the first split to be '' always, with two more fields following.

Comment: Thank you, if I got that right that means that the cause of my problem was a empty line with no text beneath my .txt file right ?

Comment: Correct.  You can check the input with the **print** statement I added inside your loop.

Comment: Why does the code print out the file object?  This doesn't seem like useful information for most purposes.

Comment: I just found out that i confused something, actually it should print (woerter) as you already suggested. I edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :-)!